# Sphinx: how to set the color of visited links (sphinx_rtd_theme)

Tags: css, colors, hyperlink, python-sphinx

I am currently creating a Sphinx document using the `sphinx_rtd_theme`. I would like to know how to change the color of visited links.

So far, I have only found possibilities using the `classic` theme (using html_theme_options in conf.py file). I however need to use 
`sphinx_rtd_theme`.

I guess there are possibilities using a local css file (in _static). For instance, I already use a css file to specify the theme color:

```
.wy-side-nav-search, .wy-nav-top {
    background: #0b750a;
}
```

Any hints?

Comment: Can you please add the HTML too and if possible, link to a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, quite easy (...). I just had to add this in my css file:

```
a:visited {
  color: blue;
}
```